# 90 degree Skew Correction for OCR in opencv python

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

Skew correction is common with OCR and my skew correction code using houghLinesP() and finding the angle of skewed image is working fine. What I wanted to ask was **how do you deal with an image skewed 90 degrees?** As the angle would probably be 0 degrees and tesseract wont extract any text.

So how to deal with this problem?

Comment: add your script whatever you have done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `osd` function of `tesseract` for skew correction. Even though for normal images skew correction using traditional image processing may work, but for scanned and low-quality images, traditional approaches might fail. So better to go with osd functionality provided by tesseract

```py
    import pytesseract
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    ###function to rotate image

    def rotate_bound(image, angle):
        """Rotate image with the given angle

        :param type image: input image
        :param type angle: Angle to be rotated
        :return: rotated image
        :rtype: numpy.ndarray

        """
        (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
        ### centroid
        (cX, cY) = (w // 2, h // 2)
        ### creating rotation matrix
        M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), -angle, 1.0)

        cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
        sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])
        nW = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
        nH = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))
        M[0, 2] += (nW / 2) - cX
        M[1, 2] += (nH / 2) - cY

        return cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (nW, nH))

    ###read input image
    image=cv2.imread('path/to/image.jpg')
    ###getting orientation info
    newdata=pytesseract.image_to_osd(image)
    ###filter angle value
    angle=re.search('(?<=Rotate: )\d+', newdata).group(0)
    print('osd angle:',angle)
    ### rotating image with angle
    skew_corrected_image=rotate_bound(image,float(angle))
    ### you can add tesseract OCR call here
```

Comment: Thanks! It solved the 90 degree skew which i was looking for. Howeever this fails to find skew angle for slightly skewed images but I already have a function for that so Thanks

Comment: Happy to help. You can give an upvote also if you found it helpful.. thanks :D